# How to access outer scope within Tensorflow Datset's map transformation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am interested to know how we may access state in "outer" scopes within the method passed to the Tensorflow Dataset's `map` transformation.

For example, if we have the following Python code (not using Tensorflow):

```
def entry():
  count = 0

  ints = [1,2,3,4,5]

  def work_with_int(i):
    nonlocal count
    count += 1
    return i + 1

  ds = map(work_with_int, ints) 

  for i in ds:
    print(i)  

  # count should be 5 now
  print("count is {}".format(count))

entry()
```

We would expect to see that the value of `count` is 5 after we iterate through `ds`. This is because, in each call to `work_with_int`, we assign to the `count` variable defined in the scope of `entry`.

Let's suppose we wish to achieve similar behaviour using Tensorflow Datasets:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

def entry():
  count = 0

  # 'ints' represents the items in the Tensorflow Dataset
  ints = [1,2,3,4,5]

  # define a method that operates on each item in the Dataset
  def work_with_int(i):
    nonlocal count
    count += 1
    return i + 1

  # create Dataset and map
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(ints).map(work_with_int)

  # as we iterate through the dataset, the 'work_with_int' method will be called
  for i in ds:
    print(i)

  # count should be 5 now
  print("count is {}".format(count))

entry()
```

In this case, however, `count` remains at 1 after iterating through `ds`.

1. Is there any reason for this behaviour?
2. Is there a way to access "outer" scope from within `work_with_int` in the second example?

Answer (score 0):

**In my view,tensorflow build a gragh in start,and run gragh when execute sess.run().you not run gragh,so your code about gragh not execute.**
**In addition,a part of code will be discarded when build gragh.SO,even if,we run gragh,not 
accumulation**